# How iterate through a set and add together the results each time?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, set

Im trying to iterate through a set of events and get the start and end time of each event and calculate the duration of each event. I then need to add all the durations together to get the total time. The code i am using is only getting the duration of the last event, and it isn't adding them all together. Im not too sure if the loop i'm using is correct?

```
Set<Event> events = eventService.findByUsers(user);
Long duration = null;

for(Event event : events)
{
    LocalTime startTime = event.getStart().toLocalTime();
    LocalTime endTime = event.getEnd().toLocalTime();

    duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toHours();
    System.out.println("The time bewtween shifts is " + duration);

   Long totalTime = duration += duration;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please refrain from initializing numbers with null. Use the primitive 'long' and use the default initialization like so 'long duration;'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the declaration of the `totalTime` variable outside the loop:

```
Set<Event> events = eventService.findByUsers(user);
long totalTime = 0;
for(Event event : events)
{
   LocalTime startTime = event.getStart().toLocalTime();
   LocalTime endTime = event.getEnd().toLocalTime();

   long duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toHours();
   System.out.println("The time bewtween shifts is " + duration);

   totalTime += duration;
}
```

With your current approach, the `totalTime` variable is initialized again with each iteration, hence will contain only the last duration at the end.

Comment: You can use a `long` instead of a `Long` and last line doesn't look right.

Comment: `totalTime = totalTime += duration` should be `totalTime += duration` dublicate assignment is not necessary

Comment: this and OP should not initialize 'duration' with null.
Actually writing 'long durantion;' or 'long totalTime;' is sufficient as the default initializationvalue of long is '0'

Comment: That's a matter of opinion I guess. I don't like default initialization of (primitive) variables for many reasons (readability for new Java programmers who might not know all default values for instance). Also Oracle calls relying on such default values [generally bad programming style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).